# Как правильно спарсить данные регуляркой по нескольким ключевикам одновременно и добавить в один list в С#?

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, linq

```
string pt1 = @"(\S*)" + tblkey1 + @"(\S*)";
string pt2 = @"(\S*)" + tblkey2 + @"(\S*)";
string pt3 = @"(\S*)" + tblkey3 + @"(\S*)";
string pt4 = @"(\S*)" + tblkey4 + @"(\S*)";
string pt5 = @"(\S*)" + tblkey5 + @"(\S*)";
var matches1 = Regex.Matches(result333 , pt1 , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
matches1 = Regex.Matches(result333 , pt2 , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
matches1 = Regex.Matches(result333 , pt3 , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
matches1 = Regex.Matches(result333 , pt4 , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
matches1 = Regex.Matches(result333 , pt5 , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

string[] matchedLines1 = matches1.Cast<Match>()
    .Select(u => u.Groups[0].Value)
    .Where(l => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l))
    .ToArray();

lock ((finedkey))
    {
    finedkey.Add(matchedLines1[0]);

String word = null;
String tb = null;

int countt = .Count;

foreach (var p in finedkey)
    {
    if (countt == 1)
        word = word + Convert.ToString(p);
    else
        word = word + Convert.ToString(p) + ",";
    countt--;
    }
tb = "w";
```

так в переменной "tb" всегда повторяется одна и та же строка, так понял это первое совпадение, как правильно вытаскивать совпадения по всем пяти кейвордам если будет совпадение хотя бы по одному кейворду или по нескольким? не получается разобраться помогите решить проблему пожалуйста...

Comment: Регулярное выражение может не дать вам ожидаемого результата. Для одного символа даст, а для более одного будут глюки.

Comment: она дает нужный результат если один кей парсить значит и по остальным так же должен по факту ,  а ваш вариант парсит все подряд да и не совсем подходит под мои требования к сожаленью...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ на ваш вопрос `|` разделитель or-условий в регулярке,

т.е. `(\S*)tblkey1(\S*)|(\S*)tblkey2(\S*)`

Я бы сделал так:

```
var matches1 = (new Regex( @"(\s*)" 
  + string.Join(@"(\s*)|(\s*)", 
   new string[]{ tblkey1, tblkey2, tblkey3, tblkey4, tblkey5 } )+
  @"(\s*)",  RegexOptions.IgnoreCase ).Matches(result333 );
```

Думаю список удобнее хранить в массиве, массив с помощью join в регулярку. У меня с \S не работает как надо, поставил \s, но можно и другие граничные условия привести. **Предупреждаю** сразу, полученый список ещё нужно обработать trim или ещё чем-то, т.к. *граничные символы \s*  попадут в match. Возможно от них можно избавится так:

```
string[] matchedLines1 = matches1.Cast<Match>()
.Select(u => u.Groups[0].Value.Trim())  // Добавил Trim()
.Where(l => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l))
.ToArray();

String word = String.Join(",",matchedLines1); // дополнил
```

Так же возможно прийдётся туда добавить в граничные условия запятые точки или другие символы, ну и так же и удалять их из списка, возможно тоже regex.

Comment: ошибка "string не содержит определение для join" как это исправить, честно признаюсь с join не разу не работал до этого...

Comment: Случайно, Join с большой буквы, да, и хвостик можно без цикла с помощью Join.

Comment: не каких изменений  что мой код что ваш выдают тоже самое: "в переменной "tb" всегда повторяется одна и та же строка"

Comment: сори не заметил дополнение щас попробую с ним...

Comment: если совпадения есть то пишет тупо сами совпавшие кейворды в  "word"  чет не могу понять в чем причина не как...

Comment: вроде решил проблему , спасибо за ответ отлично работает ваш вариант ...